# C-Send awk script to Linux

Tags: c, linux, awk

I'm writing a C program to run in Linux.
There are two command below that one can run, but one failed. I thinks the reason to fail for the second is I used "if".
But I can successfully run the awk itself in shell. Why it doesn't work in this C program ?

As you can see, command14 runs well but comm not.
Thank you!

```
char* command14="cat /var/log/messages | egrep error | awk '{print $1,$2}'| sort|uniq -c |     awk '{print $1,$2,$3}'>> data14";
    system(command14);    
char* comm="awk '{if($2=="Aug"){print $1,8,$3}}' data14>>key14.txt";
system(comm);
```

Comment: You probably need to escape some of those characters in your command.  http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~liberti/public/computing/prog/c/C/FUNCTIONS/escape.html

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I just added \ before " then it worked!!! Thanks again!!

Comment: Oh, what jmatthew said....

Answer (score 3):

```
char* comm="awk \'{if($2==\"Aug\"){print $1,8,$3}}\' data14>>key14.txt";
```

Comment: I don't know if the \' are needed, probably not.

Comment: Seems \ is ok for that part. Thank you!